# Highcharts :: Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, highcharts

```
    <?php
for ($i= 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    if ( $i <= 9)  { 
    $month = '0' . $i;
    } else {
    $month = $i; 
    }
   $date = date("d");
    $year = date("Y");
    //$month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y').'-'.$i.'-'.date('d')));
    $month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date."-" . $i ."-". $year));  
    $where = array('created_time >=' => $month . " 00:00:00", 'created_time <=' => $month . " 23:59:59");
    $i_result[$month] = count($this->db->where($where)->get('tbl_opportunities')->result());

}    var_dump( $i_result); 
   ?>
```

I am trying to generate month recap charts. It is giving me the correct result for today's stats, but for the next days the stats refresh and give the new stats. But I would like to have a cumulative of total result for that particular month (monthly basic). Any suggestions?..

Refer to the image - just the blue bar:

[image]

Comment: Your question isn't that clear. But just a hint, do something regarding your query. If you want the total accumulative result in a month then use SUM.

Comment: Dear Ronald, any sample how do i use SUM. tq

Answer (score 0):

manage to solve the problem...Tq

by replace this line

$where = array('created_time >=' => $month . " 00:00:00", 'created_time <=' => $month . " 23:59:59");

to

$where = array('created_time >=' => $year . "-" . '0' . $i . '-' . '01', 'created_time <=' => $year . "-" . '0' . $i . '-' . '31');